# how to check duplicate data in gridview in c#

Tags: c#

i have a two gridview with columns and fieldname is same.
how to check if there is the same data in gridview first to second gridview?

this is my code.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gvwListCC" runat="server" Width="340px">
<Columns>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="No" FieldName="Sequential" Width="10px"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="IdDivisi" FieldName="RowId" Width="175px" Visible="false"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Divisi" FieldName="NamaDivisi" Width="300px"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn ReadOnly="True" Caption="Action" Width="30">
        <DataItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDeleteCC" OnClick="btnDeleteCC_Click" OnClientClick="return GetDeleteCC(this)" CssClass="lookupstyle" Text="Delete"
                idDivisi='<%# HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("RowId").ToString()) %>'
                namaDivisi='<%# HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("NamaDivisi").ToString()) %>'></asp:Button>
        </DataItemTemplate>
    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
</Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>

<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gvwListTujuanInternal" runat="server" Width="340px">
<Columns>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="No" FieldName="Sequential" Width="10px">    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="IdDivisi" FieldName="RowId" Width="175px" Visible="false"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Divisi" FieldName="NamaDivisi" Width="300px"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn ReadOnly="True" Caption="Action" Width="30">
        <DataItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDeleteTujuanInternal" OnClick="btnDeleteTujuanInternal_Click" OnClientClick="return GetDeleteTujuanInternal(this)" CssClass="lookupstyle" Text="Delete"
                idDivisi='<%# HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("RowId").ToString()) %>'
                namaDivisi='<%# HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("NamaDivisi").ToString()) %>'></asp:Button>
        </DataItemTemplate>
    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
</Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

please how to create logic in c# with my problem ?thanks...

Comment: How grids are filled with data? Anyway 30s searching gave some results: http://aj-learning.com/blog/compare-two-gridview-rows-asp-net/

Comment: @Reniuz , How to using "gridview1.Rows" in devexpress gridview ? because, when my code => gvwListCC.Rows , error .Thanks